# Concurrent remote desktop in windows with multiple session support

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vnc, rdesktop

I'd like to have a remote desktop solution that allows me to connect to remote PCs even while other users are logged in, using a different session. The whole idea is that the user working locally in the remote system can work normally without being disturbed by the remote user.

I have tried [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com) but I couldn't figure out how to enter into an independent session.

I have also read about [a hack](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/13/enable-multiple-concurrent-remote-desktop-connections-or-sessions-in-windows-xp/) for Windows XP ([also for Windows 7](http://www.blogsdna.com/2336/enable-multiple-user-accessconcurrent-user-sessions-for-remote-desktop-on-windows-7.htm)) but I'd let it as a last resort solution since it's rather nasty.

Comment: It was possible under windows XP ( I have used it) trough hack and there was also hack for Windows 7 beta. Suggest you do search in Google for "Concurrent Remote Desktop Sessions Windows" - many results do pop out but I have no first hand experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this as standard with the desktop operating systems as they are specifically configured to be single user systems. You can do it with the server versions of Windows but that's a bit drastic (and expensive for home use). As you say, there are hacks about to give multiuser functionality, but these do have licence implications, and there used to be some boards and apps that allowed multi-user operation but I haven't come across any recently.

Answer (score 4):

The hack is your only option unless you have a server version of windows there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: OK, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, look at a few of my answers....

Comment: @Sergio i use the hack in windows 7. It works perfect.

Comment: This is a bad idea. It probably contains a rootkit or trojan

Comment: @GeorgeWBush - It's never good to assume. Most hacks actually make products better and more capable like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the built-in Remote Desktop Assistance?

Go to Help and Support, select Remote Assistance, and send your self the invitation!

EDIT: Silly answer.. of course you can't legally have more than one active session.
On Win7 though, you can at least log on without interrupting the current user's session. THey will simply be locked out. Which is cool.