# Does Windows allow multiple (remote) logins to the same account at the same time via whatever means?

Tags: windows

I understand that Windows can allow multiple different user logins to the same machine at the same time, either via remote desktop program such as Citrix or other means.

My question is that, does Windows allows multiple same user login to the same machine at the same time? Let's say, I have an account with the user name **John**, and this **John** gives the account name and password to his niece, and now both of them want to log into the Windows machine *at the same time* and do different things-- ***via remote login***.

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: Are both people physically at the same computer? Or do you mean remotely logging into a user profile? There is a group policy for Windows domains that allows concurrent logins, if that's any help.

Comment: Remote logging.

Comment: The same computer at once? How would that work? Or do you mean, different computers networked, and the same username?

Comment: @Gravitron remote logging disables the user profile in use, when using default Windows software. I assume all other solutions do as well.

Comment: @ekaj, I don't understand how your comment relates to my question.

Comment: ... it clearly relates. You didn't specify "remote logging" when I had posted that comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, but only on server editions (unless you are willing to do some dll hacking). If you are running a server edition un-check the following box under the properties page for remote desktop session host.

[image]

Comment: Note that if you want more than two simultaneous logons you have to purchase special client access licenses, in addition to the server license.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it's possible, if you are running a Server version of Windows and you've configured concurrent remote sessions for users.

Client versions of Windows (Home, Pro, Enterprise, etc.) do not allow concurrent, active user desktop sessions of any kind, due to licensing.

Additional info:

- [How many concurrent RDP Connections on Windows 7 Pro, Enterprise and Ultimate?](https://superuser.com/questions/123229/how-many-concurrent-rdp-connections-on-windows-7-pro-enterprise-and-ultimate)
- [Is there a way to allow concurrent remote desktop users on XP without changing dlls?](https://superuser.com/questions/48061/is-there-a-way-to-allow-concurrent-remote-desktop-users-on-xp-without-changing-d)
- [Concurrent remote desktop in windows with multiple session support](https://superuser.com/questions/250473/concurrent-remote-desktop-in-windows-with-multiple-session-support)