# Use remote computer desktop win7 - win xp

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, remote-access

I need to use via my laptop (windows 7 installed on it)  my office pc computer with windows xp on board.   You can say try to use teamvieawer, radmin etc.... But main trouble is that i must to use it so, that user, who works on pc is didn't disturbed by my "manipulations", so i can use same computer with own tasks on it, but user can do him work and i didn't interrupt user work: nobody can see each other actions. But with teamvieawer is so, that user stop work, and i use pc, and user see what i do. But didn't need this. How to do this in mode, in which i didn't interrupt user work? )

Windows remote desktop is good, but there are troubles with logins, and loged in users...

Also this pc is in subnetwork, so my modem-router has static ip, for example **.**.**.87 and my pc has ip 192.168.1.2 in this network, but i must connect to him, for example via **.**.**.87:port

Have you any ideas?

Comment: Is English not your native language? Please edit your question and repeat what you said in your native language, other users of the site may understand how to read it and can edit your English version to make it easier to understand.

Comment: So you want to access your office PC and spy on another employee who's using it? What makes you think your employer will be okay with this?

Comment: @Karan not exactly. I need to use computer on which user works, so that i didn't interrupt user work, i use this computer and work with it, and user work with it, nobody interrupt other work. In case of teamviewer i need to stop user work, and use computer, but i need some multithread like windows remote desktop do...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i edited i little bit question. Also all was ok, main idea is good describen in question... Maybe not so good with grammar, just try to read it one more time.

Comment: Now I understand, I answered a similar question in "[Does Windows allow multiple (remote) logins to the same account at the same time via whatever means?](http://superuser.com/questions/442882/does-windows-allow-multiple-remote-logins-to-the-same-account-at-the-same-time)", you should take a look at that question.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible with the server versions of windows, the desktop versions only allow one user to be connected at a time unless you do some [DLL hacking](http://www.techjam.gr/2012/os-tricks/enable-multiple-remote-desktop-user-logins-windows-7/).

There also may be some [3rd party](http://www.citrix.com/) remote desktop software (real remote desktop, not just remote viewing like LogMeIn or Teamviewer, the "spy" programs) that will allow it, but I never have worked with that kind of software so I don't know.