# How can several users connect to the one account via RDP?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, user-accounts

I have one account on my Windows XP. If i login to account and then try to login via RDP to the same account - firts user will be logged off. I need that 2 users can work at the same time in one account. How can i do this? Maybe i need to change something in gpedit.msc? Can i do this programmatically?

Comment: Googling the phrase 'multiple rdp xp' returned more than a handful of how-to's on this subject.

Comment: I'm not only need "multiple RDP Sessions", i also need connect to the same account. I didn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The license of Terminal Services (Remote Desktop Services) is not aimed to enable multiple accounts on Windows Desktop versions. It is not legal.

If you try to google the following words : "remote desktop on windows xp 2 users", you find the for example the page http://www.vladan.fr/multiple-rdp-sessions-on-windows/ which explains how to hack the terminal services. Use at your own risk and do not forget to backup the file Termsrv.dll.

Comment: I'm not only need "multiple RDP Sessions", i also need connect to the same account. I didn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

With XP it's not possible because of the way Windows is built. Windows stores the user's settings (HKCU in the Registry) to a file called ntuser.dat. Whenever an user logs in, this file is locked because it gets modified, and will be unlocked only when user logs out. Multiple concurrent logins for the same user leads to "last writer wins" problem. Apparently Microsoft has addressed this with newer OS:s.

Sources:

1. [Does Windows allow multiple (remote) logins to the same account at the same time via whatever means?](https://superuser.com/questions/442882/does-windows-allow-multiple-remote-logins-to-the-same-account-at-the-same-time)
2. https://serverfault.com/questions/298418/roaming-profiles-simultaneous-logins-of-same-user
3. https://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/04/microsoft-tackles-the-last-writer-wins-problem-of-roaming-profiles-in-windows-7-server-2008-r2/