# Multiple instances for multiple sessions in RDP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, vmware, windows-98

I recently created a  VMWARE ESXI Server for the sole purpose of splitting the software's I need into their required operating systems, but there's an issue, The software's that need to be run are single user use ONLY, meaning that only 1 user can use this at a time if any other user try's to run it, it would either not open or give an error till the other one is closed... So is there any way to create separate instances for each user that connects to the VMware so that they can use the software without problem? Looking for a solution that is support by windows 98/xp/7 as those are the softwares

Edit for easier understanding : What I’m basically trying to say here is either a way to crack the termserv.dll in the windows directory to be able to login multiple Rdp connection to a single user meaning 3-4 people using the same user but having their own instances, or a way for those 3-4 users to have their own instance meaning their own separate account logged in with no other accounts login to be able to run those single user use applications without issue

What I’m mainly trying to look for is concurrent Rdp sessions for a single user account having their own instance

I need something like this but on normal windows
[https://superuser.com/questions/442882/does-windows-allow-multiple-remote-logins-to-the-same-account-at-the-same-time#:~:text=Yes%20it's%20possible%2C%20if%20you,concurrent%20remote%20sessions%20for%20users](https://superuser.com/questions/442882/does-windows-allow-multiple-remote-logins-to-the-same-account-at-the-same-time#:%7E:text=Yes%20it%27s%20possible%2C%20if%20you,concurrent%20remote%20sessions%20for%20users).

Hopes his helps understand my question well

Comment: Please explain better what you mean when you say this software is "single use only". Is that a license limit and it checks for available licenses before allowing the software to run, or is it seeing the process running on the same computer already, or something else?

Comment: by "Single use only" I meant was it was only used for single users ONLY As in if it is opened in one user the other users won't be able to use it since its already active and opened, there is no license limit but I believe it maybe looking for process running already on the same VMware.

Comment: So it is a remote or virtualized application, like a Citric app? That sounds like a server config issue, and something that needs to be far better expounded and explained in the question.

Comment: It’s a VMware containing windows xp pro sp3 so I doesn’t seem like a server issue let me edit my question for easier understanding

Comment: I suspect you are looking for Terminal Services in Windows Server.

Comment: I have done my research on it and yes I am looking for a terminal server dll to help me run multiple users connecting through via RDP to a single user having their own instance, I had found a solution but sadly it only works with windows 7

Comment: Windows XP is a single user operating system. There are ways to make it multiuser, but I don't know how these will interact with Terminal Server. Will the application run on Server 2003? That is a full server OS and is of the same generation as XP, and it will support multi user operations more natively.

Comment: I believe they should work but then a problem arises these are all in vmdk files would there be any way to shift them to windows server 2003 without losing any data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to actually bypass the restriction for apps, you can have concurrent user logins in windows server (legally) in a single and other users as well. BUT it does the same thing whether your on another user, it's not possible unless you edit or do something in its database, I believe.